# bluemix delivery pipeline fails with server error

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline

I created a new application in a new (empty) space and when I try to deploy it, it fails with this error:

> Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host
>   is taken: IoT-DEMO-POC

Comment: I solved this error by filing in an application name in the configuration screen. However not if fails with "Domain mybluemix.net not found". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different route because the host is taken. See http://iot-demo-poc.mybluemix.net/

You can get a random route if you run the push command with `--random-route`

```
cf push --random-route
```

You can also open the `manifest.yml` file and change the `host` parameter if there is one or the application `name`. The route needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved both issues now, it seems that particular functionalitly is not available on the UK server. By deploying it on the US server, it worked fine.